# Bizarre patterns in retrieving from and submitting to atlas mongo db with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made a program with a game.  The game is supposed to register and display the most recent scores.  However, in testing, I've discovered a bizarre pattern.

I'll start the server.  The first five times I try to play the game and submit my score, it will always successfully submit the new score to the database.  Only about half the time will the scoreboard in the html document update, so submission to the database works perfect every time, retrieval works about half the time.  The sixth time I try, the program always breaks.  Neither submission nor retrieval works anymore. The values I tried to submit will show up on the scoreboard when I restart the server, but the order is off, the latest score submitted not showing up on top, earlier scores showing up above it.

I thought the fact that it runs five times successfully before breaking might be linked to the "5" in the ".limit(5)", but changing that did not help.  Can someone see what's wrong with this code, why it always breaks on my sixth attempt?

```
    require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(mongoURI);



//this presents the game page
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/newScore", function(req, res){
    addScore(req.body);
})

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    player: String,
    score: Number,
    time: Number,
    sps: Number
});

const Scores = mongoose.model("Score", schema);

//this is used to get the scores to the board
app.get("/showScores", function(req, res){

showScores();

async function showScores(){

//let newScores = new Score({player: data.username})
console.log("showScores server command firing");

await Scores.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(5).then((data) => res.json(data));
}

})

//this adds scores to the db
async function addScore(data){


console.log("adding score");

let newScore = new Scores({
    player: data.playerName,
    score: data.score,
    time: data.time,
    sps: (data.score/data.time).toFixed(2)
                            })

await newScore.save();

console.log("new score added")
}




app.listen(3000);
```

(EDIT: Front end code...

```
        <head>
<style>
    img {
        width: 200px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
    {
        img
        {
            width: 100px;
        }
    }

    #gameBoard
    {
        cursor: url("hammer.cur"), auto !important;

    }


</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Timer: <span id = "timer">0</span></p>
<p>Start Game:</p>
<button onClick = "beginGame('none')" class = "begin">Infinite Time</button>
<button onClick = "beginGame('oneMin')" class = "begin">One Minute</button>
<button onClick = "beginGame('twoMin')" class = "begin">Two Minutes</button>
<button id = "stop" disabled>Stop</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
score:<span id = "score">0</span>
<div id = "gameBoard">
<img id = "im1" src = "hole.png"><img id = "im2" src = "hole.png"><img id = "im3" src = "hole.png"><br>
<img id = "im4" src = "hole.png"><img id = "im5" src = "hole.png"><img id = "im6" src = "hole.png"><br>
<img id = "im7" src = "hole.png"><img id = "im8" src = "hole.png"><img id = "im9" src = "hole.png"><br>
</div>
<h2>Recent Scores:</h2>
<div id = "scores"></div>
<script>
    //this doesn't always fire, but bas
    function showScores(){
        $.get("/showScores", function(data){
            console.log(data.data[1])
           for (let x in data.data)
            {
                console.log(data.data[x])
                
                $("#scores").append("<br>Player Name: " + data.data[x].player + "<br>Score: " + data.data[x].score + "<br>Time: " + data.data[x].time + "<br>SPS: " + data.data[x].sps + "<br>");
                

            }
        })
    }

    showScores();

</script>
</body>
```

Script file code:

```
let time = 0;
let score = 0;


function beginGame(limit){

    function add2time()

{
    time += 1;
    $("#timer").text(time);
    if(limit == "oneMin" && time == 60)
    {
        cease_and_eval();
    }
    if(limit == "twoMin" && time == 120)
    {
        cease_and_eval();
    }
}

const timeInterval = setInterval(add2time, 1000);



const hit = new Audio("hit.flac");
const miss = new Audio("miss.mp3");
$(".begin").prop("disabled", true);
$("#stop").prop("disabled", false);

function moveMole(){    
let moleSpot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;


//needs to be 10, otherwise mole gets stuck in last hole
//this basically wipes the slate clean before placing a mole, so there won't be more than one on the screen a a time.
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("im" + i).setAttribute("src", "hole.png");
  
}

//this places the mole in a new spot
document.getElementById("im" + moleSpot).setAttribute("src", "mole.png");

}

const moleMovingInterval = setInterval(moveMole, 1000);


//I'm putting the stoping function inside the beginGame function.  Otherwise it doesn't recognize
//the intervals.
function cease_and_eval(){



    //this is the ceasing
    console.log("this function is firing")
clearInterval(moleMovingInterval);
clearInterval(timeInterval)

//now, before the everything resets, it somehow needs to ask the player for a username, and pass
//score and time data in somme sort of function.

let newPlayer = prompt("You scored " + score + " points in " + time + " seconds, or " + (score/time).toFixed(2) + " points per second." +  
    "Enter your name if you would like to post your score.")

console.log(newPlayer);

let scoreData = 
{
playerName: newPlayer,
score: score,
time: time,
sps: (score/time).toFixed(2)
}

if (newPlayer != null){
    $.post("/newScore", scoreData)
}


score = 0;
time = 0;
$("img").attr("src", "hole.png");
$("#score").text(score);
$("#timer").text(time);
$("#stop").prop("disabled", true)
$(".begin").prop("disabled", false)
$("#scores").empty();

showScores();

}


//if I don't use this "off" thing the event handlers start stacking
$("#stop").off("click");
$("#stop").click(function(){
cease_and_eval()
});

$("img").click(function()
{
    
    
    if($(this).attr("src") == "mole.png")
    {
        hit.pause();
        hit.currentTime = 0;
        hit.volume = 0.3;
        hit.play();
        
    $(this).attr("src", "whacked.png");
    score++;
    $("#score").text(score);    
    }
    else
    {
        miss.pause();
        miss.currentTime = 0;
        miss.play()
    }
})


}
```

Note I'm only using the "infinite time" button for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Defining your functions inside your route handlers and then calling them is a bit of an anti-pattern in Node.js. It is better to define your functions in a module (seperate file) and export them. This will allow you to import them where you need them and then execute them. This modular approach allows code sharing throughout projects.

Anyway, to get your application working as expected you need to make a few modifications. You don't seem to be handling any errors and not always returning a response in the right way so you are getting unexpected behaviour. Delete your `addScore()` and `showScores()` functions and implement these changes:

```js
app.post("/newScore", async function(req, res){ //< Mark callback as async
   try{ //< Use try/catch to handle any errors you may not be aware of
      let newScore = new Scores({
         player: req.body.playerName,
         score: req.body.score,
         time: req.body.time,
         sps: (req.body.score/req.body.time).toFixed(2)
      });
      await newScore.save();
      res.status(201).json({ //< You need to return a response
         message: 'New Score added'
      })
   }catch(err){ //< Catch any errors and log them in console
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      })
   }
});


app.get("/showScores", async function(req, res){ //< Mark callback as async
   try{
      const data = await Scores.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(5);
      res.status(200).json({ //< You need to return a response
         data: data
      })
   }catch(err){ //< Catch any errors and log them in console
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      })
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but all that seems to change is that there is no longer a meltdown on the sixth submission.  I still have the problem with the scoreboard not updating every other time, and the console isn't logging any errors.

Comment: @De2nis you would need to share your front-end code so that I could see where the bug is.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, busy week.  Here is the front end code:

Comment: <script>
 //this doesn't always fire, but bas
 function showScores(){
  $.get("/showScores", function(data){
   console.log(data.data[1])
           for (let x in data.data)
   {
    console.log(data.data[x])
    
    $("#scores").append("<br>Player Name: " + data.data[x].player + "<br>Score: " + data.data[x].score + "<br>Time: " + data.data[x].time + "<br>SPS: " + data.data[x].sps + "<br>");
    

   }
  })
 }

 showScores();

</script>

Comment: Hmmm that didn't come out well, I'll edit it into my post.

Comment: @De2nis what event is triggering the `showScores` function on your front-end?From what I can see you have defined a function that makes a request to `/showScores` and then you invoke it once `showScores();` straight after it's been defined. That will only fire once by my understanding. If you want the scores to keep updating and keep appending to the DOM then you need to trigger the `showScores` function as many times as you want it to update.

Comment: There's a script file attached to the front end that fires it.  Hold on, I'll edit my post again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you the code that I checked.

```
showScores();

async function showScores(){

//let newScores = new Score({player: data.username})
console.log("showScores server command firing");

await Scores.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(5).then((data) => res.json(data));
}

})
```

=>

```
showScores();

async function showScores() {
  try {
    console.log("showScores server command firing");

    const scoreData = await Scores.find().sort(_id).limit(5);
    res.json({
      data: scoreData
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("showScore error:", error.message);
    res.json({
      error: error.message
    })
  }
}
```

I wonder why you unneeded brackets `})` after `showScrores()` function's last bracket. It would be cause an unexpected error.